# Install error in simpleCV for Python

Tags: python, simplecv

I just used SimpleCV1.3 superpack to install. I can use Python shell and import SimpleCV. However, when I want to open the SimpleCV Shell, it showed the error like below.

[image]

I saw the Shell.py in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\Shell/.

And found "from IPython.terminal.embed import InteractiveShellEmbed"

I guess that it's a version error. Different IPython version may not have define_magic. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Finally, I do not use simpleCV shell in windows. Just use idle to implement simpleCV.

Comment: I also prefer to use OpenCV